# ValidationError giving me exception

Tags: python, django

My admin:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.foo == True and obj.bar == '':
            raise ValidationError('Please enter the password.')
```

My model is:

```
  foo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  bar = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to validate the models that when `foo` is True the `bar` can't be null. But It is giving me the 500. `Exception Value: [u'Please enter the password.']`

Comment: Well yes, that's what you're telling it to do.

Comment: well, I want to return this error in django admin.

Comment: I am trying to show the 'error message' in similar manner django admin does.

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to do your validation [in the `ModelForm`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin), not the `ModelAdmin`.